# Android camera widget that can be used before login

Tags: android, camera

I'm looking for an Android (phone) camera widget that I can use 'outside of' the login.
Reason: to be able to quickly take a photograph without having to log in (I use a password, and my phone locks automatically after 10 minutes)

Security is important of course:

- Should require an absolute minimum of permissions
- Just takes pictures and stores them somewhere on the phone; it should not have the option to browse through photographs taken, to change settings etc
- Easy interface
- Free would be nice, but if it's good, I'll pay
- My phone is not rooted and I would like to keep it that way

An example of such an app is e.g. the VLC media player: its entire interface outside of the login is a play/pause/stop and two next/prev buttons (and the title of the media file playing).

Android version is currently 4.2.2, running on a FairPhone (and it has some additional software running called Caju version 1.1). [It is possible to have the camera on the lockscreen if you swipe-to-unlock, but not with pin or password](https://fairphone.zendesk.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200789736-Camera-on-Lockscreen). I need that last option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out (by accident) that if I swipe my lock screen to the left, the camera comes up and I can take photos.

How I could've overlook that all the time....

I'm not sure if this was present in Android 4.2 all the time, or if it is something that the manufacturer added.